# How know if bucket exists in AmazonS3 SDK 3.0

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Currently I am working in CRUD operations using Amazon S3 for 3.5 .net , I am using 3.1.5 version.

I found this code to check if the bucket exists :

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client ();
 ///setup the client configuration

S3DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName);
                bucketExists = directoryInfo.Exists;
```

Is there another elegant way (c# code) to check if the bucket exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is written in c#, you are looking for other way to check if the directory exists? I think your way is better.

You can create a list of all the subfolders in the root and store it in other place (text file or list or whatever you want) and then you don't need to create every time connection to amazon.

```
S3DirectoryInfo s3Root = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "bucketofcode");
foreach (S3DirectoryInfo subDirectory in s3Root.GetDirectories())
{
    Console.WriteLine(subDirectory.Name);
}
```

From here https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx2N8LWZYHZHGQI/The-Three-Different-APIs-for-Amazon-S3

Comment: Yes, I am , my task is check if the bucket name exists using access key and secret Key, if bucket does not exists , I have to create the new the bucket with the default region. thanks for information and suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

I originally followed the answer here but I switched to a slightly different method so I thought I'd share it. This method creates the bucket if it doesn't already exist.

```
internal async Task CreateBucketAsync(string bucket, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bucket)) return;

    using (var amazonClient = GetAmazonClient)
    {
        if (AmazonS3Util.DoesS3BucketExist(amazonClient, bucket)) return;
        await amazonClient.PutBucketAsync(new PutBucketRequest { BucketName = bucket, UseClientRegion = true }, token);
        await SetMultiPartLifetime(amazonClient, bucket, token);
    }
}
```